# Subdomains + Integration Tests in Continuous Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, continuous-integration, subdomain

I'm trying to use Codeship Continuous Integration, which runs all of my selenium/integration tests.

My Rails app has some special subdomain logic in the `routes.rb` file, which I have included an example of below.

The problem is I can't edit the `/etc/hosts` file in the CI environment, so when my Rspec suti runs and tries to access a subdomain using my `UrlHelper` module the server cannot be reached.  For example, it tries to contact `subdomain.localhost:3000`

Any idea on how to handle reaching these subdomain-specific URLs in CI?

Code from the gist:

**domain_constraint.rb**

```
class DomainConstraint
  def initialize(domain)
    @domains = [domain].flatten
  end

  def matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? ? domain_to_match = request.subdomain + "." + request.domain : domain_to_match = request.domain
    @domains.include? domain_to_match
  end
end
```

**integration_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Something", js: true do
  it "is a fake spec" do
    # this won't work in CI/test environments
    # 'another.localhost:3001' is not mapped in /etc/hosts
    visit foo_path(subdomain: 'another')
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints DomainConstraint.new(['subdomain.domain.com', 'another.domain.com']) do
    resources :foo
  end
end
```

**url_helper.rb**

```
module UrlHelper
  def with_subdomain(subdomain)
    subdomain = (subdomain || "")
    subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?
    [subdomain, request.domain].join
  end

  # allow link_to :subdomain => ""
  def url_for(options = nil)
    if options.kind_of?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:subdomain)
      options[:host] = with_subdomain(options.delete(:subdomain))
    end
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using xip.io, which essentially accomplishes the same thing as editing your `/etc/hosts` file with custom DNS.

http://www.chrisaitchison.com/2013/03/17/testing-subdomains-in-rails/

Comment: Except your test suite now relies on having the internet, anyone know how to solve this without using a dns redirect to localhost service?